# problem with errors_add_to_base Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

My problem is the next:

I have a method which validate the image dimension

```
  def validates_attachment_dimension
    aspect = self.width / self.height
    if aspect < 0.95 || aspect > 1.05
      errors.add_to_base("La imagen '#{self.photo_file_name}' debe tener un aspecto cuadrado")
    end
  end
```

I have a parent model which have a relation with other model for images (child).

So when i inspect the @parent_model the render view (I inspect in @parent_model.errors...errors.child_model.base)
The @parent_model.errors don´t have the errors (only save the first error of child_model)

However when i read the errors attribute in child_model are fine (@parent_model.child_model.errors...).

Why have I got this problem? 
How can i show the errors for various models simultaneously?

Comment: `add_to_base` adds errors for the "base" i.e. the model and not for any particular field of that model (the difference between `add_to_base("xxx")` and `add(:name,"too long")`). `add_to_base` does not mean "add errors to parent association".

Comment: @Zabba OK I use 'add_to_base' method because I want show custom errors with full_messages (I don´t display the attribute name). So how can i use 'add' method and don´t show attributes name

Comment: @Zabba thanks.I use 'add' method. so i use the photo_file_name as attribute to show and the message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replace 'add_to_base' method by 'add' method. Then SO I can display a custom message.

Thanks  Zabba